# imap and ifilter vs. generator comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, iterator

I'm curious about the insignificant technical details -- differences between these two in python's internal representation, performance and stuff like that.

Comment: I think this is overly vague, you should try asking some specific questions.

Comment: I changed the question to be a little less subjective. I agree that these two methods are almost the same and chosing between them is pretty subjective, but I'm interested in the little technical details :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using map and filter is discouraged, but you are mapping-filtering by just one function, they are useful. But never use map or filter with lambda Consider this:

Places where filter or map is better:

```
(i for i in iterable if i), filter(bool, i)
(int(i) for i in iterable), map(int, i)
```

See, they are simplier. But, consider this:

```
(i+3 for i in iterable), map(lambda i: i+3, iterable)
(i for i in iterable if i.isdigit()), filter(lambda i, i.isdigit(), iterable)
```

And one advantage for generator expressions, you can mix map and filter functionality.

```
(f(i) for i in iterable if g(i)), map(f, filter(g, iterable))
```

For me the rules are:

- Never use lambda in map or filter.
- Only use map or filter if it's obvious what you are doing.
- For everything else, use generator expressions.
- If in doubt, use generator expressions.

**Edit:**

Forgot one important thing:

On Python versions older than 3, map(and filter) is eager, so it's better compare it with list comprehensions. But on Python 3, map is lazy, it acts like generator expressions.

Comment: I wasn't the one, but I think he/she may had a problem with you talking about `map` and `filter`, while OP asked about the `itertools` functions `imap` and  `ifilter`

Comment: It also doesn't explain why filter and map are 'better' in some cases and not others (simply because it looks simpler/cleaner?) nor why one should never use lambdas in filter and map.